# Linking UIComponents when value is NOT set

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I've added two product attributes. The first is a dropdown type, lets call it `group_applied`. The second is a text type lets call it `more_details`.

### What I need

In the admin when `group_applied` has any value selected then `more_details` should be hidden as it doesn't apply anymore and should not be used. When `group_applied` is blank (or null or zero or generally falsey) then `more_details` should be visible and available for editing.

### What I can do

Using a DataProvider I'm able to setup an imports link between `group_applied` and `more_details` et voila I can show `more_details` when `group_applied` **is set**. But oops, this is backwards to the logic I need.

### What I need help with

Is there a way to get an element to be visible when a dropdown **is not set** without needing to create a whole new UIComponent since all I need is a simple isEmpty() observable to a dropdown?

### What I have so far

Here's a code stub that ties the elements in a DataProvider (with the inverse logic to what I need).

**MY/MODULE/adminhtml/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->

    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Hidable" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">My\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Hidable</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**MY/MODULE/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Hidable.php**

```
<?php

namespace ShipperHQ\Shipper\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductAttributeGroupRepository;

class Hidable extends AbstractModifier
{
    protected $locator;
    protected $attributeRepository;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $productAttributeGroupRepository;

    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        ProductAttributeGroupRepository $productAttributeGroupRepository
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->productAttributeGroupRepository = $productAttributeGroupRepository;
    }
    
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $attr = 'more_details'
        $group = $this->getAttributeGroupCode($attr);
        if ($group) {
            $container = &$meta[$group]['children']['container_' . $attr];
            $node = &$container['children'][$attr]['arguments']['data']['config'];
            $node['visible'] = 'false';
            $node['imports'] = [
                'visible' => '${$.provider}:' . self::DATA_SCOPE_PRODUCT . '.'
                    . 'group_applied'
            ];
        }
            
        return $meta;
    }
    
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
    
    protected function getAttributeGroupCode($attrCode) {
        $attributes = $this->getProduct()->getAttributes();
        if (!isset($attributes[$attrCode])) {
            return false;
        }
        $groupId = $attributes[$attrCode]->getAttributeSetInfo()[$this->getProduct()->getAttributeSetId()]['group_id'];
        $group = $this->productAttributeGroupRepository->get($groupId);
        $groupCode = $group->getAttributeGroupCode();
        return $groupCode;
    }
    private function getProduct() {
        return $this->locator->getProduct();
    }
    private function getAttributeSetId() {
        return $this->getProduct()->getAttributeSetId();
    }
}
```

I've done **tons** of testing with import and I've given up on my ambitions that there's a way to setup this logic in the import property directly. But I'm looking for a lightweight workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add method in js component, import data into different variable and use not operator in your js method.

Second solution you can use ! in import, I found an example:

```
'visible' => '!${$.provider}:${$.parentScope}.canEdit'
```

Comment: Your second solution is the answer. I'm **sure** I tried that first before doing anything else and it didn't work. But clearly it does. So weird.... I'll take it though.  Thank you!

Comment: can we access value of `getMeta()` method as like  `getData()` method?